# Is it useful for performance to clear arrays after use?

Tags: php, arrays, memory, memory-management

Is it useful to clear an array after it served its purpose?

```
$mediaUgly = simplexml_load_file('media.xml');
$mediaNice = json_decode(json_encode($mediaUgly),true);
```

The XML-file has around 50kb. I don't know how large *$mediaUgly* will be in the memory, but I don't need it anymore as soon as I have *$mediaNice,* and later on I will derive a couple more arrays out of *$mediaNice*.

I don't experience any speed issues, but I wonder whether it is a virtue to release memory as soon as I can, thus for instance by assigning something very small:

```
$mediaUgly = 0;
```

Comment: `unset($mediaUgly)` and the interpreter will decide at some point in the future to reuse the memory previously used by `mediaUgly`, when it needs more memory.

Comment: This is just a rationalistic guess, i suppose, as was my question.

Comment: It is, more or less, [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php).

Answer (score 1):

Once something's in memory, there's no real performance gains by clearing it. Clearing it is good practice if you're done with the data, just to make room for other objects. If you keep accumulating lots of data that you're never going to use again in the rest of your script, it increases the memory usage of the script itself, which can be significant when it's multiplied across multiple child workers in the web service.

On a side note, why are you converting the XML structure to an array with json_encode/json_decode? Generally speaking, you have better handling of the data through the SimpleXML object than you do with an array, and doing the json thing -IS- a performance hit.

Get comfortable with the SimpleXML commands and you'll be glad you did!

Comment: Thanks! I embrace the whole perfume of SimpleXML! It is simple when I want to pick one certain element. The array above is for looping.

Comment: You can loop with SimpleXML, too.